# SQL query to get last dated item

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to perform a reasonably complicated query but cannot figure out how to do it as a single MySQL query.
Given 3 tables

employees, offices, employee_notes

Where employees are not directly linked to offices because they can move offices regularly. When they move, employee_notes are updated with the new office id. So each row in the employee notes has an office_id, employee_id and date of switch. If I want to get the current office id of a given employee, I could do:

```
 SELECT en.office_id FROM employee_notes AS en WHERE en.employee_id =
'userid' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

However, if I am given an office, i.e. I have the office_id, and I want to  get all employees working at that office at a given date, I am unsure how to do the query.

My first attempt is something like:

```
SELECT emp.* FROM employees AS emp WHERE emp.id = (SELECT en.employee_id FROM employee_notes AS en WHERE en.date < 'somedate' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1);
```

The problem is, in the above query the inner SELECT doesn't filter employee_notes that have the given office id. So I could do:

```
SELECT emp.* FROM employees AS emp WHERE emp.id = (SELECT en.employee_id FROM employee_notes AS en WHERE en.date < 'somedate' AND en.office_id = 'someOfficeId' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Then the inner query ONLY looks at offices that have the office id 'someOfficeId'. e.g. if employee A worked at someOffice' one week ago, but then changed to another office, the inner query wouldn't recognize this and the whole query would give me employee A as an empoyee at someOffice.

So, my next idea was to take the **en.office_id = 'someOfficeId'** outside the inner query.
e.g.

```
SELECT emp.* FROM employees AS emp WHERE emp.id = (SELECT en.employee_id FROM employee_notes AS en WHERE en.date < 'somedate' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) AND en.office_id = 'someOfficeId';
```

However, this gives a MySQL error since I am referencing the en alias in a WHERE clause. 
I'm not really sure what to try next.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick to get the most recent office:

```
SELECT en.employee_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(office_id order by date desc), ',', 1) as office_id
FROM employee_notes en
WHERE en.date < 'somedate'
GROUP BY en.employee_id
HAVING office_id = 'someoffice';
```

You can also do this with a `join` and aggregation:

```
select en.*
from employee_notes en join
     (select employee_id, max(date) as maxdate
      from employee_notes en2
      where date < 'somedate'
      group by employee_id
     ) ed
     on en.employee_id = ed.employee_id and en.date = ed.maxdate
where en.office_id = 'someid';
```

Comment: Hmm... This gives me the employee_notes as a result, not the employees

Comment: @Caveman . . . It gives you the `employee_id` and `office_id`.  You can join in appropriate reference tables that you need.  I note that this is consistent with the examples you have in the question.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I did an inner join of your second example with the employees and it seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Gordon tried a more elegant/sophisticated solution. 
I attempted to stick to the basics... and hopefully you can say I had some success.

```
/* how do you know, however, to which office an employee belongs if he/she had no switch whatsoever? is there an office field in the employees table ? */
SELECT NVL(n.office_id, e.office_id ) officeId, NVL(n.employee_id, e.employee_id) employeeID
FROM
   /* gives the last switch per employee (employees not listed here had no switch) */
   (SELECT employee_id, date_of_switch
    FROM employee_notes n
    GROUP BY employee_id, max(date_of_switch)) m,
    /* join with employee_notes to get the office of the last switch */
    employee_notes n,
    employees e
WHERE
    /* if employee is not listed in M, he/she had no switch */
    e.employee_id = m.employee_id (+)
AND n.switch_date = m.switch_date
AND n.employee_id = m.employee_id
ORDER BY 
  officeId
```